# Keep line break from SQL server to HTML

Tags: html, asp.net, wcf, line-breaks

I am storing a text in a SQL server database as a `varchar(MAX)`.
I have to display this text in my web page.
The problem is that the text contains line break.
When I go in the HTML source code, I can see the line breaks but it does not display them in the web page.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try use for particular column, for example `record.ToString.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"<br>")`

Comment: Do you know how I can use that in a linq query ?

Comment: there is just simple example `Dim tt() As String = {"First" + Environment.NewLine + "record", "Single line record", "Again record with" + Environment.NewLine + "new line"} :
        Dim list = (From t In tt Select t = t.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br>")).ToList()` .... try to implement in Your code.

Comment: This has nothing to do with SQL, it's about HTML. What  language/framework are you using to generate HTML? You should replace newlines with `<br/>` or create paragraphs in your page code. Please specify what stack you are using in order to get specific answers

Comment: I am using angularsJS to fill my HTML page

Answer (score 1):

Line breaks are ignored in HTML at the display level. Replace these linebreaks with `<br/>` tags:

```
SELECT REPLACE(column_name, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '<br/>')
FROM table_name
```

Comment: Thx. But i am retrieving the data with linq query. How can i use this with à linq query ?

Comment: Line breaks are not really _ignored_, by the way, they're treated as whitespace. That is, a line break looks just like a space.

Comment: @Weedoze this should be done at the page/controller level, not at the query level. How are you generating the page? This isn't really a SQL related question.

Comment: @Weedoze and how do you get the data from the database to the browser?? C#, PHP, MVC or not, node.js ? ASP.NET MVC, Web API, Web forms?

Comment: JavaScript calling à REST service (wcf)

Answer (score 0):

instead of storing line break in database, store the HTML content with all the formatting and 
 tags.

Comment: The text come from an XML file and I already tried to add <br/> at the end of the sentence

Comment: can you please post the logic that you are using to display the text in the page.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way around this without manipulating your SQL. Use a paragraph tag WITHIN a pre tag like so...

```
 <pre><p>Your SQL Would Go Here</p></pre>
```

You can then use some CSS for your pre tag to wrap the text...

```
    pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* Since CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
    }
```